# What are the benefits of having history tables in an ERD?

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I trying to model horse racing in a database and have been presented with two alternative ERDs. I'm no, expert on database design and was hoping someone could lay out for me the advantages/disadvantages of Alternative A vs Alternative B.  Is it a case of one being preferable to another absolutely or is A preferable under certain circumstances (what are those circumstances) an B better in other circumstances.

From my very inexperienced perspective, it appears that it would be easier to query Alternative B.

[image]

versus
[image]

Comment: What is "Starter" in this diagram?

Comment: @Brian A starter is a horse that participates in a races.  Starter could also be thought of as entries in a race or a horses past performances.

Comment: It's impossible to be certain from such an abstract diagram, but if `STARTER` tracks the participation of horses and jockeys in races over time, then it sounds like `JOCKEY_HISTORY` could be redundant and be derivable from the former by a projection without the `RACE` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debater brings up some good points that you should certainly consider.

Based on your reply to my question, I would suggest the following structure (which you'll see is quite similar to "B").  I pulled the fields for the Horse and Jockey tables pretty much out of thin air - if they don't fit your needs, obviously you'd ignore them and store whatever you need.

```
Horse
    ID    primary key (in each table)
    Name
    Age
    Gender
    etc.

Jockey
    ID
    Name
    Height
    Weight
    etc.

Race
    ID
    Post_Time
    Distance
    etc.

Starter
    ID
    Race_ID    foreign key to Race
    Horse_ID   foreign key to Horse
    Jockey_ID  foreign key to Jockey
    Gate
    Finish_Position
    etc.
```

With this structure, a race is an event that happens at a specific time and that involves specific horses and riders.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Industrial databases tend to have a lot of historical (logging, auditing, trail, etc) tables in them. Typically there are more of these kinds of table than anything else.

Real-world applications tend to need this information. Often there is a requirement for auditing (who did what, when, how and why, etc.). Often there is a requirement for an 'undo' function, which needs the historical data to disentangle things. Sometimes there is a requirement for analysis of past performance and so on.

I've noticed that commercial databases often have no deletion of data. Records just change status (e.g. by having a 'Historical' flag set). I've also noticed that commercial and industrial databases tend to have huge numbers of tables, many of which are no longer used or needed (but nobody had the time to weed out).

Perhaps worth mentioning is that the sooner you start collecting historical data, the more you will have when you come to have a need for it.

And I suppose that is why multi-terabyte disks are selling like hotcakes.

I suggest you give thought early to how your old data is to be archived away (or deleted), before you get to a crisis.

Another point to mention is that data protection laws may require you to delete some data in a timely (and thorough) manner.